# Google visualization "chart not drawn"

Tags: google-visualization

I have a draw script. It seemed to work previously, but I had to reconfigure a few things. I compared the code which creates it with the old version and compared the script with a similar script I created for creating column charts. They all seem to line up, but this version doesn't render. I get the following in my Chrome Developer tab:

`format+en_GB,default+en_GB,ui+en_GB,corechart+en_GB.I.js:1269`

Render Script:

```
<div id="chart_div1"></div>
<div id="png"></div>
<script>
google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
function drawChart() {
var dt = new google.visualization.DataTable({cols:[{id:'activity',label:'Activity',type:'string'},{id:'size',label:'size',type:'number'},{id:'compositeutility',label:'compositeutility',type:'number'}],rows:[{c:[{v:'AH32HH2050_3p'},{v:220325.0},{v:220974.256897}]}]}, 0.6);
var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div1'));

var actOrCom = ""
    if (actOrCom=="activity"){
         chart.draw(dt, { width: 800, height: 250, hAxis: {title: 'Activity', titleTextStyle: {color: 'red'}}, series:{0:{targetAxisIndex:0},1:{targetAxisIndex:1}}, vAxes:{0:{title:"size"},1:{title:"compositeutility", titleTextStyle: {color: 'red'}}}
    });
    }
    else if (actOrCom=="commodity"){
        chart.draw(dt, { width: 800, height: 250, hAxis: {title: 'Commodity', titleTextStyle: {color: 'red'}}, series:{0:{targetAxisIndex:0},1:{targetAxisIndex:1}}, vAxes:{0:{title:"size"},1:{title:"compositeutility", titleTextStyle: {color: 'red'}}}
    });
    }
document.getElementById('png').outerHTML = '<a href="' + chart.getImageURI() + '">Printable Version</a>';
}
</script>
```

Comment: Is the div with the id of "sd" on your page?

Comment: Sorry. I copied the wrong code. That was a similar, but working, section.

Comment: Where is `actOrCom` getting set to either of the values you're testing for? Also, generally, you have `if/else if/else` rather than as you have it set up. Maybe you need an `else` block to default to?

Comment: That was the issue. actOrCom is a Django context variable. I changed the name of it when I changed things around. I would generally have an else statement, but with the way it's set-up server-side, it defaults to "activity" if no value exists so that should act as an else.

Comment: You should also wrap your `chart.getImageURI` call inside a "ready" event handler for the chart, as there is no guarantee that the chart will be finished drawing when that call is made otherwise.